# Why with every zoom out and zoon in, my data points get closer to each other

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a chart which displays data from a CSV based on the interval selected (hours, days, weeks, months). I am able to update my scale dynamically but every time if I zoom out (first) and then zoom back in (strictly this sequence), my data points get closer and closer to each other. Below are my codes. Could anyone advice me where went wrong? Thanks!

```
d3.csv('data/sample.csv', function (data) {
    // sort out the data we'll be using
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = new Date(d.dateTime);
        d.Ranking = +d.weight;
        d.Interval = d.level;       
    });

    // define the boundaries of the svg canvas
    var margin = {top : 30, right : 45, bottom : 30, left : 45},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // define the scale for each axis
    var interval = 'hours';

    var mindate = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.date; });

    var minDate = mindate.getDate();
    var minMonth = mindate.getMonth();
    var minYear = mindate.getFullYear();

    var minHour = mindate.getHours();

    var mindate = new Date(minYear, minMonth, minDate, minHour);

    var maxdate = new Date(minYear, minMonth, minDate, minHour + 5);

    console.log(mindate);
    console.log(maxdate);

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([
            //d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.date; }), 
            //d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date; })
            mindate, maxdate
            ])
        .range([0, width])
        .nice();

    var xDaysScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2014, 7, 1), new Date(2014, 7, 6)])
        .range([0, width])
        .nice();

    var xWeeksScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2014, 7, 1), new Date(2014, 7, 31)])
        .range([0, width])
        .nice();

    var xMonthsScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2014, 7, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 1)])
        .range([0, width])
        .nice();

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).range([height, 0]).nice();

    // define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(d3.time.hours, 1)
        .orient('bottom');

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');

    // define the zoom behavior
    var zm = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(xScale)
        .scaleExtent([.1, 1024])
        .on('zoom', zoom);

    // initialize the tooltip, and append it to the body
    var tooltip = d3.select('body')
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .attr('id', 'tooltip')
        .style('opacity', 0);

    // initialize the chart
    var svg = d3.select('.graph')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('svg:g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

    // append the manipulation areas to the chart
    svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom xy')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .call(zm)
    .on('dblclick.zoom', null) // disable the standard shitty doubleclick zoom function
    .on('dblclick', function (d) { // use my own awesome zoom function, that resets the chart
        // reset the main scale
        zm.scale(1);
        zm.translate([0, 0]);

        // let's not forget to update the axes
        svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
        svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);

        // apply the changes
        update();
    });

    // append the axes to the chart
    svg.append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-' + width + ', ' + height + ')')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

    // create the elements based on the data provided
    var elem = svg.selectAll()
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'element')
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' + xScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
        });

    // we append the full text description as a HTML element, because, a text element is more expensive, and doesn't support line breaks
    elem.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 1000)
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .attr('class', 'fulltext')
    .html(function (d) {
        return d.content;
    })
    .style('opacity', 0);

    // function::zoom - handles the scaling, translation of the chart elements
    function zoom() {
        //svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
        //svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);

        //update();

        if (zm.scale() < 1) {
            //console.log('zooming OUT');

            if (interval == 'hours') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xDaysScale).ticks(d3.time.days, 1).orient("bottom");
                zm.x(xDaysScale);
                interval = 'days';
            }
            else if (interval == 'days') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xWeeksScale).ticks(d3.time.weeks, 1).orient("bottom");
                zm.x(xWeeksScale);
                interval = 'weeks';
            }
            else if (interval == 'weeks') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xMonthsScale).ticks(d3.time.months, 1).orient("bottom");
                zm.x(xMonthsScale);
                interval = 'months';
            }
        }

        else if (zm.scale() > 1) {
            //console.log('zooming IN');

            if (interval == 'months') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xWeeksScale).ticks(d3.time.weeks, 1).orient("bottom");              
                zm.x(xWeeksScale);
                interval = 'weeks';
            }

            else if (interval == 'weeks') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xDaysScale).ticks(d3.time.days, 1).orient("bottom");
                zm.x(xDaysScale);
                interval = 'days';
            }

            else if (interval == 'days') {
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).ticks(d3.time.hours, 1).orient("bottom");
                zm.x(xScale);
                interval = 'hours';
            }
        }

        svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
        svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
        update();
    }

    // function::resize - handles the responsive positioning and sizing of elements depending on the size of the viewport
    function resize() {
        // re-get the size of the window
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // re-set the size of the chart's range
        xScale.range([0, width]).nice();
        yScale.range([height, 0]).nice();

        // configure the chart to the new size
        d3.select('.graph')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // re-set the size of the manipulation area
        svg.select('rect')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

        // re-size and re-position the axes
        svg.select('.x.axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

        // update the elements according to the resized elements
        update();
    }

    // function::update - handles all redrawing of the chart and checking of dynamic elements
    function update() {
        // re-position individual elements
        svg.selectAll('.element')
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            if (interval == 'hours') {
                console.log('hours, hour');
                return 'translate(' + xScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }

            if (interval == 'days') {
                console.log('days, day');
                return 'translate(' + xDaysScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }

            if (interval == 'weeks') {
                console.log('weeks, week');
                return 'translate(' + xWeeksScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }

            if (interval == 'months') {
                console.log('months, month');
                return 'translate(' + xMonthsScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
            }

            //return 'translate(' + xScale(d.date) + ', ' + yScale(d.Ranking) + ')';
        });

        d3.selectAll('.fulltext')
        .style('opacity', function (d) {
            // hide or show the full text descriptions based on zoom level
            if (zm.scale() >= 1) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }

    // add the event handler for resizing
    d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
    // refresh once to make sure all the processing gets through
    update();

});
```

Comment: In short, I am trying to share a common scale among 4 time intervals - hours, days, weeks, months. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using several different scales?